# <audio> tag to audioBuffer - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

My javascript-webApp first reads a short mp3 file and finds silence-gaps in it (for navigational purposes), then it plays the same mp3 file cueing it to start where one silence or another finishes.  This differs from the usual webAudio scenario designed to grant access to audio data currently being played in the stream (not to the whole track).

To get my webApp to work **I have to read/access the mp3 file twice**:

1. via `XMLHttpRequest` to read an entire MP3 file and put it in to an audioBuffer that I can subsequently decode using `audioContext.decodeAudioData()` - as explained here: [Extracting audio data every t seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676564/extracting-audio-data-every-t-seconds)
2. by specifying the `<audio>` tag to allow me to play the file on demand specifying in milliseconds the cue/start point.  [Playing audio with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript).

**Q:** Is there currently any way I might declare the `<audio>`tag first then somehow derive the audioBuffer directly from it, without resorting to `XMLHttpRequest` ?

I've [read](http://www.w3.org/2011/audio/wiki/Spec_Differences#Reading_Data_from_a_Media_Element) about `createMediaElementSource` but I can't see how to get an `audioBuffer` by using it.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: No I didn't properly give it a go

Answer (score 5):

When doing your first XHR, ask for a blob:

```
xhr.responseType = 'blob'
```

Then get an ArrayBuffer out of it:

```
var arrayBuffer;
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function() {
    arrayBuffer = this.result;
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

and give that to decodeAudioData to get the AudioBuffer as usual. You can now do your processing.

Then, when your processing is done, give the blob to the  tag, as a source, when you want to play it, it will work as usual:

```
 audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

You might need to prefix URL with the webkit vendor prefix, I can't remember if they implement the unprefixed version. Anyways, blobs are the way to go !

Comment: Thanks but, I think you missed the phrase in my question that says "without resorting to XMLHttpRequest"

Comment: This is not possible, then.The semantic of the <audio> tag is to be a streamed, cached on disk, opaque resource. The semantic of the AudioBuffer is local, decoded, planar, very fast access, data stored in memory. You can use the later in the former, but, for obvious reasons, not the opposite.