# Web audio API get AudioBuffer of <audio> element

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have an audio element

```
var audioSrc = 'https://mfbx9da4.github.io/assets/audio/dope-drum-loop_C_major.wav'
var audio = document.createElement('audio')
audio.src = audioSrc
```

I need the [`AudioBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer)
to do [beat detection](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/web-audio-beat-detector) so I tried accessing the buffer when the audio is loaded as so:

```
audio.oncanplaythrough = () => {
  console.info('loaded');
  var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(context.destination);
  console.info('source.buffer', source.buffer);
  source.start()
}
```

However, the above code snippet logs

```
> loaded
> source.buffer undefined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<audio> tag to audioBuffer - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080493/audio-tag-to-audiobuffer-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems the best way to do this is to avoid `<audio>` tags and load the audio via XHR:

```
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
const audioSrc =
  "https://davidalbertoadler.com/assets/audio/dope-drum-loop_C_major.wav";

const audioData = await fetchAudio(audioSrc);
audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioData, onDecoded, onDecodeError);

function fetchAudio(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = () => resolve(request.response);
    request.onerror = (e) => reject(e);
    request.send();
  });
}

function onDecoded(buffer) {
  // Play the song
  console.log("Got the decoded buffer now play the song", buffer);
  const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = buffer;
  source.connect(audioContext.destination);
  source.loop = true;
  source.start();
}

function onDecodeError(e) {
  console.log("Error decoding buffer: " + e.message);
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still true in 2018. The Web Audio API spec tries to suggest using the `audio` element for this, but you can't do anything with that besides basic playback: no pre-rendered audio visualization, no access to audio data, nothing.

Comment: but by doing this, you must download all the audio, causing much network traffic loss, is there a way to get these data, without fetching all the .mp3 file being used?