# Remove audible popping sound when pausing audio with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, setvaluecurveattime

When you pause an audio element with JavaScript using `audio.pause();` you can hear an audible pop.

This occurs when a waveform is stopped/cut in the middle of a wave, rather than at a zero-crossing.

I have been looking for a way to resolve this and seen a lot of people suggesting quickly fading out like this:

```
var fadeAudio = setInterval(function () {
    if (audio.volume <= 0.0) {
        clearInterval(fadeAudio);
        audio.volume = 0;
    }
    if (audio.volume != 0.0){
        audio.volume -= 0.1;
    }
}, 200);
```

This however will give a worse end result with a descending series of clicks instead.

### Edit

I have found this code to add an 'S' curve fade at the beginning of the file but am having difficulty modifying it to fade out a file instead.

```js
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var audio = new Audio('https://samples-files.com/samples/Audio/wav/sample-file-4.wav');
var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
var source = ctx.createBufferSource();

function create_curve_buffer(length, phase) {
    var curve = new Float32Array(length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        curve[i] = (Math.sin((Math.PI * i / length) - phase)) /2 + 0.5;
    }
    return curve;
};

audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(){
    source.connect(ctx.destination);
    source.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
    
    curve = create_curve_buffer(ctx.sampleRate, (Math.PI/2));
    start = ctx.currentTime;
    
    gainNode.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(curve, start, 5);
});
```

```html
<button id='play' onClick='audio.play();'>Play</button>
<br />
<button id='stop' onClick='audio.pause();'>Stop</button>
```

I have basically just tried reversing the curve by doing `curve.reverse();` after the for loop and calling the function with the stop button instead of the `canplaythrough` event.

Then I get an error saying `Failed to execute 'setValueCurveAtTime' on 'AudioParam': setValueCurveAtTime(..., 0, 5) overlaps setValueCurveAtTime(..., 0, 5)` when I click stop.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is already covered in the [MDN webaudio documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Advanced_techniques#the_final_playsweep_function). Use a GainNode and the [`linearRampToValueAtTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime) method

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Final code:

```js
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source;
var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
var audioBuffer;

async function fetchTrack() {
    var audioData = await fetchAudio("https://samples-files.com/samples/Audio/wav/sample-file-4.wav");
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioData, onDecoded, onDecodeError);
}

function fetchAudio(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        request.onload = () => resolve(request.response);
        request.onerror = (e) => reject(e);
        request.send();
    });
}

function onDecoded(buffer) {
    audioBuffer = buffer;
}

function onDecodeError(e) {
    console.log("Error decoding buffer: " + e.message);
    console.log(e);
}

function createCurve(length, phase) {
    var curve = new Float32Array(length);
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        curve[i] = (Math.sin((Math.PI * i / length) - phase)) /2 + 0.5;
    }
    curve.reverse();
    return curve;
};

async function fade(){
    var curve = createCurve(audioContext.sampleRate, (Math.PI/2));
    var start = audioContext.currentTime;
    gainNode.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(curve, start, 1);
    setTimeout(stop,1000);
}

function stop(){
    source.stop();
}

function play(){
    source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
    gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, 0)
    audioContext.currentTime = 0;
    source.start();
}

fetchTrack();
```

```html
<button id='play' onClick='play();'>Play</button>
<br />
<button id='stop' onClick='fade();'>Stop</button>
```

Comment: You dont fade in the example. The example doesn't work for me. You dont need webkit audioCOntext any more audioContext is enough. you need to start fading on stop not in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do doesn't work! Sorry this code is just garbage don't take it personal.

The Audio Element is not part of web audio api. You need to decode the whole mp4 first and load it into an audio Buffer like in this threat: [Web audio API get AudioBuffer of <audio> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856331/web-audio-api-get-audiobuffer-of-audio-element).

Then you can connect the nodes etc. If you need help connecting nodes write a new threat:

this here is false:

```
source.connect(ctx.destination);
source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
```

You dont need to connect the source with the destination.

Destination are your Speakers.

Source is your CD Player.

Gain node is your amplifier.

Think like in the real world. You can use it as in the real world. Thats the beauty of web-audio-api.

If you then just disconnect the nodes, that shouldn't cause any clicking. But i am not exactly sure.

Just answer if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a technique called audio fading. Which allows you to gradually decrease the audio volume gradually before stopping it completely.Then try to decrease the volume logarithmically

```
function fadeAudioSmoothly(audio) {
    let fadeInterval = 10; 
    let fadeStep = 0.05;
    let minVolume = 0.01   
    
    let fadeOut = setInterval(function() {
        audio.volume = Math.max(audio.volume - fadeStep, minVolume);
        
        if (audio.volume <= minVolume) {
            clearInterval(fadeOut);
            audio.volume = 0;
            audio.pause();
        }
    }, fadeInterval);
}
```

Comment: this is almost the same as what I had in the question, it results in a series of descending pops

Comment: @PaddyHallihan I made an edit which allows us to decrease the volume logarithmically. This ensures the volume doesn't fall lower than the minVolume to prevent the popping sound

Comment: there will always be a descending series of pops when using an interval

Answer (score -1):

I think this is smooth enough...

If you move too fast with the volume it starts clicking. Thats the way it is. In every software.

```js
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var audio = new Audio('https://samples-files.com/samples/Audio/wav/sample-file-4.wav');

function stop(){
  if(audio.volume<0.01){audio.volume=0}else{audio.volume -= 0.01};
  if(audio.volume <=0){audio.pause();}else{setTimeout(stop,10)}
  
}

function start(){
  if(audio.volume==0){audio.play()}
  if(audio.volume>0.99){audio.volume=1}else{audio.volume += 0.01};
  
  if(audio.volume<1){setTimeout(start,10)}
  
}
```

```html
<button id='play' onClick='audio.play();'>Play</button>
<br />
<button id='stop' onClick='stop();'>Stop</button>
<button id='start' onClick='start();'>STart again</button>
```